# How to use the libspotify api？

Tags: libspotify

This is the version of libspotify which I have download:libspotify-12.1.51-win32-release.There are an example named "spshell".
when I test the track playing and sp_session_player_play(g_session, 1) be called,I can not heard any voice.

Another question,what's the relationship between notify_main_thread and sp_session_process_events.when  sp_session_process_events (sp_session *session, int *next_timeout) is called what actually has been done and what's the effect of the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the spshell demo streams music at all.

sp_session_player_play instructs libspotify to start providing you with the audio data. It does not play it for you. You must provide spotify with a [music_delivery](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.45/structsp__session__callbacks.html#a33a31478b8de1882ad7847ad033fbaeb) callback to receive the audio data, and then you must arrange to play it yourself. Look at the jukebox example.

notify_main_thread is called when libspotify needs sp_session_process_events to be invoked on the main thread. Your callback should perform whatever notification is necessary to wake up the main thread and then return without waiting for it. You must not call sp_session_process_events from the callback, or you will deadlock the program.

When sp_session_process_events is called, libspotify will perform necessary processing that it has to do on the main thread, such as updating user-visible data structures. The [second parameter](http://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.45/group__session.html#gaff27cb730db6debf55e750e39e7fadd7) is an output parameter. When sp_session_process_events returns, the pointed-to value is the time in milliseconds until you next need to call sp_session_process_events. Thus there are two reasons you might need to call sp_session_process_events: after this timeout has passed, or when notify_main_thread has been invoked.